# Tell if an object's attribute has been used

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know which attributes have been used at the end of an interaction with an object.

I thought about using decorators (a counter or sth) around getters to detect if the method has been called, but one can access the attribute directly.

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x
    def __str__(self):
        return "<x: {}>".format(self.x)
```

```py
xx = X()
print(xx)
print(xx.x)
```

I want to get : attribute x was used 2 times or three (in `__init__` while initialising).

Comment: Umm... why twice? either it's once (accessed outside the object itself) or three times? Or are you not counting the use in `__init__` ? Or not counting the use outside the object itself? What are the exact rules here?

Comment: What if there's multiple attributes... what's the scope of something "being used"?

Comment: sorry, I've just edited the post, but getting count for only uses inside the object itself will be great

Answer (score 2):

Use a property:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self._xcounter = 0
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        self._xcounter += 1
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        # you can also update _xcounter here if you want 
        # to count write access too, or use two counters
        # (one for read and one for write)
        self._x = value

    # exposes xcounter as a read-only property
    # so we don't break encapsulation
    @property
    def xcounter(self):
        return self._xcounter 

    def __str__(self):
        return "<x: {}>".format(self.x)

xx = X()
print(xx)
print(xx.x)
print("xx.x was used {} times".format(xx.xcounter))
```

> getting count for only uses inside the object itself will be great

This might get more tricky - technically speaking, [a method is really a function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod) (hence the `self` parameter - else the function couldn't access the current instance) so there's no real notion of "inside the object". You could of course reverse the use of the property (keep `x` as a plain public attribute, add a private `_x` property and only use the private property internally), ie:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self._xcounter = 0
        self._x = x

    @property
    def _x(self):
        self._xcounter += 1
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def _x(self, value):
        self.x = value

    # exposes xcounter as a read-only property
    @property
    def xcounter(self):
        return self._xcounter 

    def __str__(self):
        return "<x: {}>".format(self._x)
```

but that looks a bit like a WTF to me. FWIW, may I ask which problem you're trying to solve with this feature ?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist sorry for having been faster ;-)

Comment: what? no! no need to be sorry! good for you! and your answer was already more elaborate by that point anyway.